# When an Apostate takes 'Extra Spells', do they need to study to learn the spells?

Tags: spellcasting, invisible-sun

When an Apostate takes 'Extra Spells', do they need to study to learn the spells?

Or once the Crux is spent, are they instantly usable by the Apostate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that it's GM discretion. My GM has said that the normal studying time applies to my apostate PC unless I have a good reason why I should get to skip it, i.e. something my character has been fiddling with or working on in down time, a problem I've been trying to solve for some time, that kind of thing. I would ask your GM -- or, if you are the GM, what do you think is reasonable, given the description of how apostates learn & teach themselves?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you support your answer by citing relevant evidence?